# How do I bind the right value of this in javascript class callbacks?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

```
class SomeClass {
  constructor() {
     this.x = 0;
  }
  getSomething(inputVal) {
   let self = this;
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function(){
     if(inputVal){
       self.x = 1;
       resolve();
     }
     else{
       self.x = -1;
       reject();
     }

   }, 10);
 });
}
```

I am having to use a variable called `self` to refer to `this`. Is this wrong to do? if not, how else do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this wrong to do?

No, obviously that method it's not wrong, it's just a way to keep a **reference** to `this` object.

But there are some alternative ways for this problem:

### 1. Use `bind` method.

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

```
getSomething(inputVal) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(function(){
                if(inputVal){
                    this.x = 1;
                    resolve();
                }
                else{
                    this.x = -1;
                    reject();
                }

            }.bind(this), 10);
        });
 }
```

### 2. Use `arrow` functions.

Until `arrow` functions, every `new` **function** defined its own `this` value.

For instance, `this` can be a new object in the case of a constructor.

```js
function Person(age){
  this.age=age;
  console.log(this);
}
let person=new Person(22);
```

Or `this` can **points** to the `base` object if the function created can be accessed like `obj.getAge()`.

```js
let obj={
  getAge:function(){
    console.log(this);
    return 22;
  }
}
console.log(obj.getAge());
```

An `arrow` function does not create its own `this`, it's just used the `this` value of the `enclosing` execution `context`. In the other hand, `arrow` function uses `this` of parent scope.

```
getSomething(inputVal) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (inputVal) {
                this.x = 1;
                resolve();
            }
            else {
                this.x = -1;
                reject();
            }

        }, 10);
    });
}
```

Comment: I am getting a syntax error when I put the `.` next to `}`

Comment: @RanjithRamachandra, I edited answer.

Comment: i dont think you cant .bind(this) in arrow function

Comment: @AmitWagner, yes, sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation

Comment: @RanjithRamachandra, you're welcome.

Comment: Could you also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47767279/how-to-test-for-a-propety-of-a-class-after-promise-resolution-with-mocha-and-cha? I am such a noob with newer JS frameworks and unit testing

Answer (score 1):

```
class SomeClass {
    constructor() {
        this.x = 0;
    }
    getSomething(inputVal) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (inputVal) {
                    console.log(this.x);
                    this.x = 1;
                    resolve();
                }
                else {
                    this.x = -1;
                    reject();
                }

            }, 10);
        });
    }
}

const test = new SomeClass();
test.getSomething(true);
```

use arrow function in setTimeout